# How to extract webpage data as quick as possible?

Tags: python, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to read more than 100 transactions but the problem is, it is very slow and does not seem to be efficient for longer list of transactions. I have added a code for one transaction. It creates browser object, load the page and then read, which consumes lot of time. Is there any efficient way of reading some content of the page?

```
from selenium import webdriver

PATH = 'C:/Users/.../Desktop/Py/chromedriver.exe'

# A list of all transactions, only one transaction
transactions = ['0x483250bcd0d94becc904446a0aac44d55e4f8084a4a5bfd928934507196aed83']
for trans in transactions:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
    driver.get('https://bscscan.com/tx/'+trans) # buying Safemoon
    nRows = int(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_maintable"]/div[7]/div[1]/div/span[2]').text) 
    
    for row in range(1,nRows+1):
        myText = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="wrapperContent"]/li[{row}]/div/span[6]').text
        print(myText)
    
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many options, **[Scrapy](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/)** is one of them, **[Beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)** is another library that works, even you can check the requests done by the browser on each page and try to reply with http **[Requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/)**

Comment: is it possible to convert above code as you mentioned? Which of the suggested option does not open browser window and still get content of the page?

Comment: Beautifulsoup and Scrapy, take a look on example codes and you can decide which code looks more readable, then you can choose one because still you can search by xpath in both, so in requests you can do it but its not their core.

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy or requests with multithreading both can process 100 transactions in seconds

In your above code, change to this to increase execution speed

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    
    PATH = 'C:/Users/.../Desktop/Py/chromedriver.exe'
    
    # A list of all transactions, only one transaction
    transactions = ['0x483250bcd0d94becc904446a0aac44d55e4f8084a4a5bfd928934507196aed83']
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
    
    for trans in transactions:
        driver.get('https://bscscan.com/tx/'+trans) # buying Safemoon
        nRows = int(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_maintable"]/div[7]/div[1]/div/span[2]').text) 
        
        for row in range(1,nRows+1):
            myText = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f'//*[@id="wrapperContent"]/li[{row}]/div/span[6]').text
            print(myText)
        
   driver.quit()
```